# How to detect if camera is moving or shaking using homography | Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am currently developing a system to detect and flag changes in camera position between pairs of subsequent frames.

The idea is to detect when a camera moves away from its initial position, and flag the frames that have undergone position change.

The process currently works as follows:

1 - Detect keypoints between pairs of frames using ORB.

2 - Match those keypoints, and filter out good matches. (This helps to ignore 
    moving objects in the scene)

3 - Calculate homography between frames using cv2.findHomography

Now that I have stored the homography matrices, is there a calculation I can perform on them to detect changes in camera position between frames?

I was thinking that I need to decompose the homography matrices and extract rotation & translation, then perform some calculation on those values?

I hope I was able to articulate this well enough, any and all help is greatly appreciated, Code and output is below.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

path = 'sb-190//*.jpg'

#get frames
frames = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(path)]
n_frames = len(frames)

#iterator
i = 0

while i < len(frames):

    curr = frames[i]

    if i == 0:
        #store initial frame
        initial = curr
        initial_gray = cv2.cvtColor(initial, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        prev = curr.copy()

    curr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(curr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(prev, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #feature extraction sift is scale invariant
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()

    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(curr_gray, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(prev_gray, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

    #matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(curr_gray, kp1, prev_gray, kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=2)

    #filter good matches
    good = []

    for m in matches:
        for n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.2 * n.distance:
                good.append(m)

    if len(good) > 10:
        pts1 = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        pts2 = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)    

        M, status = cv2.findHomography(pts1, pts2)
        h, w = curr.shape[:2]
        pts = np.float32([[0,0], [0,h-1], [w-1, h-1], [w-1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        print(M)
        print()
    else:
        cv2.imshow('current', curr_gray)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1000)

    if key == 27:
        break

    prev = curr.copy()
    i=i+1


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output is the homographic matrices:

```py
[[ 9.98069728e-01 -8.44512083e-03  1.93805757e+00]
 [ 1.65520807e-03  9.92207941e-01 -1.32879826e+00]
 [-1.94333567e-07 -7.62519660e-06  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 9.98069728e-01 -8.44512083e-03  1.93805757e+00]
 [ 1.65520807e-03  9.92207941e-01 -1.32879826e+00]
 [-1.94333567e-07 -7.62519660e-06  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 9.98069728e-01 -8.44512083e-03  1.93805757e+00]
 [ 1.65520807e-03  9.92207941e-01 -1.32879826e+00]
 [-1.94333567e-07 -7.62519660e-06  1.00000000e+00]]

[[-1.09409512e+00  1.28808037e-01  4.30594249e+02]
 [-8.09133467e-01  9.53894733e-02  3.18403442e+02]
 [-2.54085719e-03  2.99087149e-04  1.00000000e+00]]

[[-1.09409512e+00  1.28808037e-01  4.30594249e+02]
 [-8.09133467e-01  9.53894733e-02  3.18403442e+02]
 [-2.54085719e-03  2.99087149e-04  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 1.02189803e+00 -3.32323178e-03 -1.15831742e-02]
 [ 1.31735188e-02  1.03347097e+00 -1.30685436e+01]
 [ 2.77752056e-05  2.20653391e-05  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 3.14925453e-01 -4.36827742e+00  8.45199492e+02]
 [ 7.54635765e-02 -1.04674244e+00  2.02529760e+02]
 [ 3.72604878e-04 -5.16833891e-03  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 3.14925453e-01 -4.36827742e+00  8.45199492e+02]
 [ 7.54635765e-02 -1.04674244e+00  2.02529760e+02]
 [ 3.72604878e-04 -5.16833891e-03  1.00000000e+00]]

[[-4.10062878e-01 -2.71969634e+00  1.71345949e+03]
 [-2.07256510e-01 -6.94651451e-01  5.48898050e+02]
 [-3.80097560e-05 -2.20367911e-03  1.00000000e+00]]

[[-9.13756863e-01 -3.67621908e-01  1.50169122e+03]
 [-2.61876140e-01 -1.05127674e-01  4.30295697e+02]
 [-6.08491276e-04 -2.44792762e-04  1.00000000e+00]]

[[-9.13756863e-01 -3.67621908e-01  1.50169122e+03]
 [-2.61876140e-01 -1.05127674e-01  4.30295697e+02]
 [-6.08491276e-04 -2.44792762e-04  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 1.00000000e+00  7.86948944e-14  3.26867045e-11]
 [-1.97539704e-15  1.00000000e+00  2.21256273e-12]
 [-1.66808096e-17  2.63331746e-17  1.00000000e+00]]

[[ 9.99251381e-01 -1.62125888e-02  9.64392151e-01]
 [ 4.68674990e-04  9.92419459e-01  8.32263570e-01]
 [ 4.55530113e-07 -1.82475555e-05  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: You ever find a solution to this? Would calculating moving towards or away from the vanishing point help?